# High data on recv-q buffer and thread lock on BufferedInputStream on Linux

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, sockets, smpp

We have a Java application running on Linux (Ubuntu server). We have been facing high recv-q problem since quite some time. Application gets hang and does not read data from socket every few hours. In thread dump, we have found below stack trace.

> "Receiver-146" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fb3fc010000 nid=0x7642 runnable [0x00007fb5906c5000] java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>   at java.net.SocketInputStream. socketRead0(Native Method) 
>   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150) 
>   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121) 
>   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235) 
>   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275) 
>   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334) - locked <0x00000007688f1ff0> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream) 
>   at org.smpp.TCPIPConnection.receive(TCPIPConnection.java:413) 
>   at org.smpp.ReceiverBase.receivePDUFromConnection(ReceiverBase.java:197) 
>   at org.smpp.Receiver.receiveAsync(Receiver.java:351) 
>   at org.smpp.ReceiverBase.process(ReceiverBase.java:96) 
>   at org.smpp.util.ProcessingThread.run(ProcessingThread.java:199) 
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

We are not able to trace the exact reason behind this? Kindly help.

We are using 16 core machine and load on the system is around 30-40 at the time of issue. We use command "ss dst " to find out recv-q. Recently we have been facing issues with recv-q size getting hung, were in receive buffer gets stuck at some point of time. But recvQ size is not decreasing and as a result we are losing a lot of hits from the other side, our application is not accepting any data

Comment: Have you ruled out garbage collector pauses?

Comment: @Banthar i don't this gc pause will be an issue. Because i have observed gc logs and there is enough heap space available during the issue. We are setting heap size as "-Xms512m -Xmx2500m"

Comment: Can you estimate how long are those pauses? I assume there are a lot of threads. Are they all stuck on read? You can still get a minor GC even though there is a plenty of heap. It should not stop the whole application for too long though. If `-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime` doesn't show anything, try `-XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics`.

Comment: @Banthar Below are the GC logs for your reference,


5198864.775: [Full GC (System) [PSYoungGen: 896K->0K(283712K)] [ParOldGen: 380858K->380893K(578752K)] 381754K->380893K(862464K) [PSPermGen: 30549K->30537K(30848K)], 0.2177350 secs] [Times: user=2.16 sys=0.00, real=0.22 secs] 
5198864.766: [GC [PSYoungGen: 178310K->896K(283712K)] 559169K->381754K(862464K), 0.0082610 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs] 

It seems it takes around 12 to 22 seconds for full GC

Comment: To be more specific abt hardware, below is the config :

RAM: 48 GB,
Disk Space: 1TB,
Number of core: 16,
Number of tomcats: 15,
Tomcat Memory: 2.5GB to each tomcat. 

If u want to see thread dump, it is available at [link](http://filedropper.com/thread20aug20141)

Comment: FullGC runs every hour.